# Button on click action for each table column button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, laravel-5

I have a **visitor table** where I can add visitors.  I am **displaying all the visitors in a table** I have set two **sign In and sign out button** into two column. Now when I click the sign in the button then it inserts the current time in the db and then the sign in button will be replaced and display the time that that is in the db column.  I have added a script and make a span and took retrieve the date time and **hide initially** and when the **button is clicked it's showing**. But it's **work only for the 1st visitor**. others button is not working. And when I load the page then the button comes again.  But I want, when I click the button then it will never come again then show the date time always. How can I set the operation for all button?? How can I do this using ajax calling?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#hideDate").hide();
    $("#hide").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent().hide();
    $("#hideDate").show();
    });
    });
    $('#button-to-hide').hide();
</script>
```

```

```
<td>
    <form method="post" action="{{route('signInUpdate','id')}}">
        {{ csrf_field()}}
        <input type="hidden" name="isSignIn" value="{{$internalVisitor->isSignIn}}"/>
        <input type="hidden" name="tableId" value="{{$internalVisitor->id}}"/>
        <button type="submit">
        <a id="hide">Sign In</a></button>
        <p id="p1"></p>
    </form>
    <span id="hideDate">{{ $internalVisitor->signInTime}}</span>
</td>
```

```

Answer (score 0):

looks like ids of your buttons and other elements are repeated in the table, will suggest you to use class attribute in your js code.

Comment: Please explain it with more details.

Comment: If I load the page then the function call again hide and show and button and comes again. I want to hide the button permanently after clicking it and display the date time always.

Comment: to hide the button permanently use some persistent flag you may need to add one more column to check if the user is signed in or not. put the check for this flag in your view code.

Comment: Can you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can only one ID per element in HTML. You can however have unlimited elements with the same class. So I just updated your code from id to class.

```
 <td>
<form method="post" action="{{route('signInUpdate','id')}}">
    {{ csrf_field()}}
    <input type="hidden" name="isSignIn" value="{{$internalVisitor->isSignIn}}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="tableId" value="{{$internalVisitor->id}}"/>
    <button type="submit">
    <a class="hide">Sign In</a></button>
    <p class="p1"></p>
</form>
<span class="hideDate">{{ $internalVisitor->signInTime}}</span>
```

Ofcourse your javascript needs a little update as well

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".hideDate").hide();
$(".hide").click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
$(this).parent().hide();
$(".hideDate").show();
});
});
$('.button-to-hide').hide();
```

However this is probably resulting in all the customers hiding in one click. This can be resolved by refactoring your code so it works more with $(this). Just like this:

```
$(this).find(".hide");
```

or

```
$(this).find("a");
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: It's working for the first time and only for the first button. So how can I set the button action based on every column using table id and if success then the button will never come again??